# Disable 'ag-column-hover' css class in ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is there any option to prevent ag-grid add 'ag-column-hover' class to a column? For unknown reason, this class cause some trouble with my table on mobile view.

I try to add a call back for event onCellClicked to remove the class 'ag-column-hover', it work, but ugly because the column layout will be broken about ~1s before the class was removed.

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: Yes and ...no. The task was re-assigned to an expert in front-end guy. He found out that there was a mess in css hierarchy of the project and did some magic to fix it, no js involved. Although I can still access to the repo of the project after moving to a new one but the commit is long time ago so I can not find it.

Comment: Okay thanks, In my case I changed something else. So no need to change this